# How can i shuffle the content in my tablelayout in android

Tags: java, android

Hi i'm new in creating android application and i would like to ask for help to solve my problem. my problem is i want to shuffle my Questionnaire using the tablelayout. it is possible for me to shuffle it? sorry because i'm new in java.

This is the code in xml i use:

```
<TableLayout            
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"  android:stretchColumns="*" android:background="#000000">
                    <!-- Row 1 with single column -->
                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="18dp" android:text="1. What color is at the bottom of the rainbow??"  android:layout_span="4"
                            android:padding="18dip"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
                   </TableRow>
                    <!-- Row 2 with 3 columns -->
                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent">
                        <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/answer1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer1A"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Violet" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer1B"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Red" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer1C"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Blue" />
    </RadioGroup>
                    </TableRow>
                  <TableRow
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="18dp" android:text="2. A farmer has 20 sheep and all but 15 die. How many sheep are left? "  android:layout_span="4"
                              android:padding="18dip"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
                   </TableRow>
                    <!-- Row 2 with 3 columns -->
                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent">
                        <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/answer2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer2A"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="5" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer2B"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="10" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer2C"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="15" />
    </RadioGroup>
                    </TableRow>
                     <TableRow
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="18dp" android:text="3. Yard is to inch as quart is to ?"  android:layout_span="4"
                             android:padding="18dip"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
                   </TableRow>
                    <!-- Row 2 with 3 columns -->
                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent">
                        <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/answer3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer3A"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Gallon" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer3B"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Ounce" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer3C"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Milk" />
    </RadioGroup>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="18dp" android:text="4. Pen is to poet as needle is to?"  android:layout_span="4"
                             android:padding="18dip"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
                   </TableRow>
                    <!-- Row 2 with 3 columns -->
                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent">
                        <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/answer4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer4A"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Thread" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer4B"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Sewing" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer4C"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Tailor" />
    </RadioGroup>
                    </TableRow>
                     <TableRow
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                         <Button
                             android:id="@+id/submit"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:gravity="center"
                             android:text="Submit" />

                   </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
```

Comment: do you use database for the content? if yes, instead shuffle the layout, you can shuffle the query

Comment: nope. i don't have any database. it is possible to shuffle it even i don't have any database use??

Comment: i don't even use array.. my app is already running and my prof told me to try to shuffle the question every it start the app and i don't know how can i shuffle my question. that's why i ask for a question if it possible to shuffle it in a simplest way? or should i create another code for it?

Comment: From where are you fetching questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you have set up a fixed layout using the layout editor. Due to this you cannot shuffle the existing content.

What you need is to dynamically change the layout. To do so you would need to just set the parent layout in your editor. Then in your oncreate method of the mainactivity you need to fill the table layout with table rows dynamically. This is how you will ensure that everytime the app is started the table rows are shuffled. Yes you will need a code change. Something like this to begin with

```
TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);


for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new  TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    row.setLayoutParams(lp);
    //add your buttons and stuff
    ll.addView(row,i);
}
}
```